# Fourier transform integral for even function proof

Tags: proof-explanation, fourier-transform

Using fourier transform prove that:
If $f(t)$ is even $$F(v)= 2\int_0^\infty f(t)cos(2\pi\nu t) \,\mathrm dt$$

How to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\begin{align}
\mathcal F\{f(t)\}=F(\nu)&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(t)\mathrm e^{-i 2\pi\nu t}\mathrm dt\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^{0}f(t)\mathrm e^{-i 2\pi\nu t}\mathrm dt+\int_{0}^{\infty}f(t)\mathrm e^{-i 2\pi\nu t}\mathrm dt\\
\quad&=\int_{0}^{\infty}f(-t)\mathrm e^{i 2\pi\nu t}\mathrm dt+\int_{0}^{\infty}f(t)\mathrm e^{-i 2\pi\nu t}\mathrm dt\\
&=\int_{0}^{\infty}f(t)\underbrace{\left(\mathrm e^{i 2\pi\nu t}+\mathrm e^{-i 2\pi\nu t}\right)}_{2\cos(2\pi\nu t)}\mathrm dt\\
&=2\int_{0}^{\infty} f(t)\cos(2\pi\nu t)\mathrm dt
\end{align}